# set a alarm to lambda function based on execution time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

Is it possible to set an alarm when lambda functions take more than a specific time?
ex:- I want to set alarm if my lambda function takes more than 10 seconds to execute

Answer (score 1):

AWS web console:
*CloudWatch* -> *Alarm* -> *Create Alarm*

1. Select metric:
   Rely on the standard AWS lambda metric Duration:
   [image: AWS lambda metric - Duration]
2. Set the alarm condition

[image: Alarm threshold]

then set Notification etc. depends on your needs.

3. Set the alarm name and description.

As a result you will get a needed alarm. (Screen is with lower threshold (2000 ms))

[image: Created Alarm]